# Prove that there exist 4 such planes which form a tetrahedron containing P.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $P \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be a convex polytope such that of the planes spanned by the faces, every $3$ intersect at a point, but no $4$ intersect. Prove that there exist $4$ such planes which form a tetrahedron containing $P$.

Comment: I'd start this way. Take a face, and the plane spanned by it. Then take a point of $P$ that is maximally distant from the plane. You can assume the point is a vertex of $P$.

Comment: I got you Dave. But how do you prove that there exist 4 planes which form a terahedron?

Comment: What about the original plane and the three that meet at the vertex?